# Why the difference in IOStream's EOF flag behaviour when I extract to `char` vs to `int`?

Tags: c++, iostream, eof

Recently I've come across a bug in my software that was caused by a stringstream object that had it's EOF flag set before I expected it. Even though I managed to found out what happened, I was not able to find out why this is happening. An example:

```
stringstream test ("a b");
char temp, temp2;

test >> temp >> temp2;
cout << "eof: " << test.eof() << endl;
```

When run, this shows:

```
eof: 0
```

This is the output I would expect. (I would expect the stringstream to set the EOF flag to 1 when i attempt to read something again)

However, when I make a small change to the above example:

```
stringstream test ("4 2");
int temp, temp2;

test >> temp >> temp2;
cout << "eof: " << test.eof() << endl;
```

the output shows:

```
eof: 1
```

Why does the EOF flag get set in this situation, but not in the previous one?

Comment: I would not expect the stringstream to set EOF in the initial example after another read. I'd expect it on the _fourth_ read attempt.

Comment: A bit premature to decide that this should be tagged "bugs"; it's only a bug in you! It's also not specific to `stringstream`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator>>` skips whitespace characters by default, so the first read into a char will read `a`, the second will skip  and read `b`, a third would reach the end of the string and fail, setting the eof flag.

In the `int` case, multiple characters can be read while parsing an `int` because an `int` may be represent by multiple digits. While reading the integer a second read attempt will be made after reading the `2`. This will set the eof flag for the stream although the read of the `int` will succeed.

This is why you should check `!fail()` and not `good()` to see if a read operation succeeded and why the conversion of a stream to `bool` (or `void*` in C++03) also uses `!fail()`.

Comment: That `!eof` should pretty much never be checked on its own is a good point.

Comment: Thanks a lot Charles, your explanation is very clear. This indeed also happens to reading in strings then, which makes sense given your post. There was also confusion on my part about what bits are checked when, but good checks all, while "the stream itself" (unary ! i think) checks for bad/fail only. And sorry for the bug tag, I ment it more in "bug in my program" sense, not a big in the language/compiler!

Comment: D'oh, you're right that [formatted extraction skips whitespace even for `char`](http://www.ideone.com/fmH4o). Not sure that I would have expected that.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Yes. `eof()` is the ugly in the `good()`, the `bad()` and the `fail()`.

Answer (score 8):

When you're extracting one character at a time, the stream can't know that the EOF has been reached until *you* try to extract a character that isn't there.

But when you're extracting formatted data into a type like `int`, the parser attempts to pull *as many characters out of the stream as it can* to form the number; the "tries to extract a character that isn't there" part will occur as part of this process (the final "iteration", in fact), so EOF can be set.